# can i execute javascript in href when i have text before my input?

Tags: web-application, php, xss, reflected-xss

[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11985/will-javascript-be-executed-which-is-in-an-href) is where I took this example from:

`<a href="<?php echo $_GET['e'];?>">Back</a>`

In this code, I can do `http://my_url?e=javascript:alert()`

But what can I do if my code is like this:

`<a href="e<?php echo $_GET['e'];?>">Back</a>`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes

If the data you inject is arbitrary and not filtered at all, you could inject `"></a><script>alert('XSS')</script><a href="#`

This will end up with the following DOM elements:

```
<a href="e"></a><script>alert('XSS')</script><a href="#">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Short answer is YES, Long answer is what is your PHP script sanitizing input then what you are trying to achieve might not be displayed like you want to achieve XSS